# OOP not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, oop

I'm having a problem with my code. It's giving me the two errors 'a' and 'MAX' was not declared in this scope, in int main().

I am pretty sure I defined it in my header file. I've read countless forums and tutorials and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
//main.cpp
/* A test driver for the VectorMin class (VectorMin.cpp) */
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "VectorMin.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

VectorMin c1;
std::vector <int> v1(a,a+MAX);
int min = c1.recursiveMinimumVector(v1,v1[0],1);
c1.printOut(min);
return 0;
}
```

Implementation file

```
 //VectorMin.cpp
/* The VectorMin class Implementation (VectorMin.cpp) */
#include "VectorMin.h" // user-defined header in the same directory
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
// Constructor
VectorMin::VectorMin()
{

}


VectorMin::int recursiveMinimumVector(const std::vector<int>& b, int minVal, size_t subStart)
{
     if(subStart+1 >= b.size())
        return minVal;
    else
         return recursiveMinimumVector(b, std::min(minVal, b[subStart]), subStart+1);
}
VectorMin::void printOut(int m)
{
  std::cout << "Min value= " << m;
}
```

Header file

```
//VectorMin.h
/* The VectorMin class Header (VectorMin.h) */
#include <string>   // using string

// VectorMin class declaration
class VectorMin{

private:
   static const int MAX = 10;
   const int a[MAX] = {44, 83, -14, 1, 101, -92, 23, 2, 7, 100};

public:
   // Declare prototype of member functions

   // Constructor with default values
    VectorMin();

   // Public member Functionsvoid generateRand();
    int recursiveMinimumVector(const std::vector<int>& b, int minVal, size_t subStart);
    void printOut(int);


};
```

If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong and explain why it's wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `a` and `MAX` are defined in the scope of the class `VectorMin`, not in global scope. (And they are made `private` so `main()` can't access them anyway.)

Comment: Your method definitions aren't correct either. You should put the type before the class scope. "VectorMin::int recursiveMinimumVector " should be  "int VectorMin::recursiveMinimumVector"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main`, you have these two lines

```
VectorMin c1;
std::vector <int> v1(a,a+MAX);
```

First of all, `a` and `MAX` are member variables of the `VectorMin` class, so you'd have to call them like

```
c1.a
VectorMin::MAX
```

Second of all you still can't do that because those members are `private`.

Comment: It's probably more conventional to access the static member `MAX` with `VectorMin::MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't global.

Just because you declared them in one class doesn't make them accessible to other classes. In your case, `a` and `MAX` belong to your `VectorMin` class, and aren't accessible by your `main` function.